# Как поменять тип данных в таблице PostgresSQL?

Tags: postgresql

У меня в таблице есть атрибут `char(5000)`, я хочу поменять его на тип `text`.

Возможно ли это и если да то как?

Comment: `alter table table_name alter colunm colunm_name type text` не работает? Тогда 1) добавить новое поле, 2) скопировать значения из старого в новое, 3) убедиться, что скопировано верно, 4) удалить старое поле, 5) переименовать новое в старое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предложенный [Sergey](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/192547/sergey) вариант должен работать:

```
alter table table_name alter colunm colunm_name type text
```